# Normalize By Group for All Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, normalization

I have a dataset with 400+ columns. The first two columns I want to exclude in this calculation but I want to include it in my final output.

For columns, 3:ncol(df), how do I normalize by group?

This is what I have right now but it gave me an error and it took very long to run at the same time:

```
library(BBmisc)
test<-df %>% 
group_by(group) %>% 
mutate_all(.vars = df[3:ncol(df)], 
           funs(normalize))
```

I want to be able to set the range from 0 to 5.

This is what my dataset looks like:

```
df
group    week    col3     col4    col5 ......
    A       1      25       56      87 ......
    A       2      21       34      98 ......
    A       3      34       67     100 ......
    B       1      11      120    1000 ......
    B       2       8      340    1200 ......
    B       3       2      560    2000 ......
```

I want to apply a normalization function from column 3 and on (not hardcoded to col3 to col5 because I have 400 columns in total) by group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `mutate_at`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-one_of("week")), normalize)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group  week   col3   col4   col5
#  <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A         1 -0.250  0.218 -1.14 
#2 A         2 -0.851 -1.09   0.429
#3 A         3  1.10   0.873  0.714
#4 B         1  0.873 -1     -0.756
#5 B         2  0.218  0     -0.378
#6 B         3 -1.09   1      1.13
```

---

As mentioned in the comments,if we are using a range of index, then should be careful with `mutate_at`.  Currently, the indexing starts without the `group_by` column.  So, if we wanted to pass a range of index, subtract one from the start and stop positions

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate_at(vars((3-1):(ncol(.)-1)), normalize)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group  week   col3   col4   col5
#  <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A         1 -0.250  0.218 -1.14 
#2 A         2 -0.851 -1.09   0.429
#3 A         3  1.10   0.873  0.714
#4 B         1  0.873 -1     -0.756
#5 B         2  0.218  0     -0.378
#6 B         3 -1.09   1      1.13
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), week = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), col3 = c(25L, 21L, 34L, 11L, 8L, 2L), col4 = c(56L, 
34L, 67L, 120L, 340L, 560L), col5 = c(87L, 98L, 100L, 1000L, 
1200L, 2000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: `vars` is unnecessary

Comment: @Ryan it is for general case

Comment: I get this error when I try this: `Error in combine_vars(vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n`

Comment: @nak5120  With `mutate_at`, when we specify the column index, it needs to be careful as the 'group' column is not at all included.  One option is to specify the column names or the columns that are not of interest

Comment: Thanks @akrun, appreciate it